# Vertical accordion menu css

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu

i need to adjust accordion vertical menu css.
I do not understand how to adjust the sub menu li

```
  <div id="menuleft">
    <div class="top">header</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Main 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
   </ul>    
  </div>
```

This is the css:

```
#menuleft{
position: absolute;
bottom:0px; left:100px;
height: 100%;
width: 160px;
background-color: #BAB3D6;
}
#menuleft .top{
float:right;
width: 160px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:110%;
margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
height: 30px;
}
#menuleft ul{
position:absolute;
width: 160px;
top:130px;
left:0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#menuleft li{
width: 130px;
height: 30px;
left:0; 
font-size: 95%;
line-height: 30px; 
list-style: none;
cursor:pointer;
}
#menuleft li a { 
text-decoration:none; 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
padding-left:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#menuleft ul ul li a { 
text-decoration:none; 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
padding-left:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color: #d8d4e8;
}
#menuleft li a:hover{
background-color:#652D91;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;   
}
#menuleft li a:active {
background-color:#ad45c5;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

After this I use jquery for expand and collapse submenus
Thanks in advance for the help

this is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh0td9az/1/)

**UPDATE**

With misterManSam help now it works but I have still a little problem, when I expand the sub menu their back ground is not uniform as you can see, it makes a little click, this is Jfiddle.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh0td9az/146/)

Comment: What specifically are you trying to adjust? Would you mind adding in the JS as well so the JSfiddle is functioning properly? To select the submenu for adjustments you would want to use `#menuleft ul li ul` to select the sub menu.

Comment: The submenu are not in the right position they must be between Main 1 and Main 2 so I can show and hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `position: absolute` from `#menuleft ul` and position with a top margin.
- Remove the `height` on `#menuleft li`
- Give the top level `ul` a class (here `.nav`) and style that instead of `#menuleft ul`
  so that second level `ul`s are not styled.
- Give the `.nav` the same background as `#menuleft`. This will ensure that there is a background behind the links even at very small heights.

Also, ensure that all the default margin and padding is removed from the `ul` and the list items.

### Demo

```css
ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#menuleft {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #BAB3D6;
}
#menuleft .top {
  float: right;
  width: 160px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  height: 30px;
}
#menuleft .nav {
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin: 130px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #BAB3D6
}
#menuleft li {
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 95%;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#menuleft li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#menuleft ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #d8d4e8;
}
#menuleft li a:hover {
  background-color: #652D91;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#menuleft li a:active {
  background-color: #ad45c5;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuleft">
  <h1 class="top">header</h1>

  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: excuseme @misterManSam seems I have a problem with margin and padding if I remove the universal selector *

Comment: No worries, place this *before* everything else: `ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: I should have placed that in the first place :) - I updated the answer.

Comment: I have a little problem, when I expand sub menu th back ground is not uniform, can I fix that? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bh0td9az/146/)

Comment: @AlbertoAlibaba - The problem was caused by the 100% width on `a`. I have removed all of the unneeded width on `ul` and `li` as well. You don't need 100% height / width on `a` because `display: block` elements will take up their parents width and height automatically. [Here is your new example](http://jsfiddle.net/de0dorsx/) :D

Answer (score 0):

I think when we hover into `tag` `li` and after show `ul sub-menu` . I think this code css.

```
/* This is my code */
#menuleft ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

#menuleft ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%;
}
```